# how to set up the format of a title of the tabs of Terminator?

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, configuration, xfce

I can't find any method of how to set up the format of a title of the tabs of Terminator. it's probably has to do with its config at `~/.config/terminator/config` but how exactly?

I want to shorten its title.

Comment: What do you mean by "format of the title"?  Do you want to change the text, or fonts and colors?

Answer (score 2):

Add "title" under the terminal definitions in the Terminator config, look at title under terminal1 in the example:

```
[global_config]
[keybindings]
[layouts]
  [[test]]
    [[[child0]]]
      fullscreen = False
      last_active_term = 0630e644-7c41-4da8-8fbd-85e36b825ab2
      last_active_window = True
      maximised = True
      order = 0
      parent = ""
      position = 0:0
      size = 1920, 1147
      title = "Look a window title"
      type = Window
    [[[terminal1]]]
      title = "Look a terminal tab title"
      order = 0
      parent = child0
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      uuid = 0630e644-7c41-4da8-8fbd-85e36b825ab2
```